# Creating an insert method for Linked List Collection (Java)

Tags: java, methods, insert, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create my own Linked List methods for a Collection of videogame titles/prices.  I've made some progress with my add and delete methods, but I need to make one to insert one somewhere in the list that isn't just at the end.  Either by using indexes or inserting after the other objects in the list.  I can't seem to get it to work, though.

Here's what I have so far:

### VideoGame.java

```
public class VideoGame {

private String name;
private Double price;

public VideoGame(String n, Double p)
    {
    name = n;
    price = p;
    }

public String getName() 
    {
    return name;
    }

public void setName(String name) 
    {
    this.name = name;
    }

public Double getPrice() 
{
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) 
{
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + ", " + "Price: $"+price;
}
}
```

### VideoGameNode

```
public class VideoGameNode 
{
public VideoGame data;


public VideoGameNode next;


public VideoGameNode(VideoGame s)
{
    data = s;
    next = null;


}


}
```

### VideoGameList

```
public class VideoGameList {
private VideoGameNode list;


public VideoGameList()
{
    list = null;

}
//method to add entries into the collection (at the end each time)
public void add(VideoGame s)
   {
    VideoGameNode node = new VideoGameNode(s);
    VideoGameNode current;


  if (list == null)
     list = node;
  else
  {
     current = list;
     while (current.next != null)
        current = current.next;
     current.next = node;
  }
  }
```

I have a tester/driver program, but it's kind of irrelevant to what I need help doing right now.  I can't seem to get an insert method to work properly.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `insert()` method which also takes the `position` as an argument.

Inside this method you can write the similar code which you have written for `add()` method.

You just have to define a `counter` and check an additional condition inside the `while` loop for if that `counter` equals the `position` you passed as the argument. If any of the two conditions of your loop gets satisfied then it will be terminated.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public void insert(VideoGame s, int position) {
    if (null == list) {
        list = new VideoGameNode(s);
    } else {
        VideoGameNode current = list;
        int counter = 0;
        while (null != current.next && position > counter++)
            current = current.next;
        VideoGameNode newNode = new VideoGameNode(s);
        newNode.next = current.next;
        current.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this code seems to add the new VideoGame object at the end of the list regardless of what I put in for the position number.

Comment: For some reason, when I put in anything other than 0 for the position, it returns an error of:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at VideoGameList.insert(VideoGameList.java:33)
 at VideoGameTester.main(VideoGameTester.java:27)

Comment: Line 33 is:  while (null != current.next || position > counter++)

Comment: My list already has 5 entries before I try to insert something.  Hmm.

Comment: Cool.  I'm not getting anymore errors, but it's always putting it in at the same position each time (after the first node) even if I put the position as 2, 3, or 4.  And nothing else is printing off after that (like the next nodes are removed when I try to print out the list).  I'm sorry for having so many issues lol.  I did add my driver program to the OP.

Comment: @naaros That's because we are not keeping the track of the list after insertion. I have updated the solution. This should fix it.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked!  Oooh, I see what you did. Thanks SO much for your help!  Greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: @naaros Your Welcome! :)